# How to add simple passport or basic auth to hapi

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, hapi.js, passport.js

I need some help, trying to create a simple application which will 
display a public login page and upon authentication only will redirect to index.html page..

I thought this should be pretty straight forward, have done a first step, but adding the Auth/ Passport plugin and redirects are not working..

Below is the example
https://github.com/makrand-bkar/hapi-simple-auth-tutorial

Any help very much appreciated, kind of stalled here

Mak

Comment: Did you have a look at [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) or [hapi-sol](https://github.com/yonjah/hapi-sol) ?
they both have example for basic auth. I'm not familiar with passport API but you can probably use them together by changing/adding some routes that use passport

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is the hapi auth tutorial: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth

I forked your github repo to see what you were doing, but it looks like right now you have no auth related code preset in there. Essentially what you need to do is this:

- Create a registration view that stores users in a database system like Postgres or MongoDB.
- Hash user passwords.
- Get setup with CSRF to prevent cross-site forgery requests.
- Build a login view that checks the database for the user / password hash to validate credentials.
- Use a session system (like with cookies) to persist user state.
- Build helper stuff to load users from cookies.
- Write helper stuff to check for users before allowing access to protected pages.

Now, this is obviously quite annoying to write all this yourself.

Luckily, hapi has some plugins which help with this sort of thing, namely: https://github.com/Mkoopajr/hapi-session-mongo

Hope that helps!